# What can be used for Webcommunication on Android

Tags: java, android, selenium, jsoup

I am currently building an App for Amazon FireTVStick which should be able to show content of a Website.
I am using Jsoup for HTML-Parsing and locating the Resources and this is working good and was easy with Jsoup.

But now I am stucked at the last step, in which I want to locate the videoLink.
The Page uses dynamic JavaScript to load the content and has a wait timer of 10 seconds.

Because Jsoup is only a HTML-Parser in the last step i need anything else for the communication. I have used Selenium once or twice but on Android it is not possible to use as I want with example FireFoxDriver or am I to dumb.
It needs a installation of that driver but the Stick does not have one.

Is it possible to use Selenium in any way in Android Studio building a App for FTVS or is there alternative or even a better approach to accomplish what I want ?

I do not want to automate anything on the Android device, just need something for the Webcommunication.

I hope my problem and intensions are clear.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Using Selenium for "webcommunication"? I do not understand.

Comment: What I mean is that you can simulate clicks, post forms and so on.

Comment: If it is an app, why use something as heavy as Selenium? Why not something like JavaScript and inject the events into the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android Webview is what helped me in the last step. It can execute the JavaScript and return the modified HTML which can than be parsed with JSoup. As for now it is the best solution I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you don't want a FirefoxDriver if it's an android system :) Luckily for you there is an Android version of Selenium called **Selendroid**, check it out at [this link](http://selendroid.io/).

[HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) is another alternative you might want to consider, it's basically a headless browser with support for JavaScript.

Comment: Selendroid is used for automation of a Android Device and that is what I am searching for.
And I researched HTMLUnit and it looks like it is not supported yet on Android.